# Insert data into mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This code hasn't error or exception, but after running the table `features` in the data base remain empty

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sounds","root","");
    statment = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query = "INSERT INTO featuers (avg_Bandwidth) values (?)";   
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.setDouble(1, avarage_Bandwidth);

    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

    con.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think you also have a typo in your "INSERT" statement. Shouldn't there be a "features" instead of "featuers "?

Comment: @BranislavLazic  but then it should throw `SqlException` !!

Comment: if there is no typo , Try using [Connection#commit() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29)

Comment: @NeerajJain Newly created connections (at least through `DriverManager`) are required (by the JDBC spec) to be autoCommit=true.

Comment: @NeerajJain I think, he has not read the stacktrace, he mentioned in the question that table name is `features` but in code he wrote `featuers`

Comment: One small tip too: Close connection and statements in `finally` block.

Comment: oh sorry I mean "features" instead of "featuers"
but although that, the table remain empty :(

Answer (score 1):

Two things of note :

1. `statment = (Statement) con.createStatement();` 
   This variable is not used if I see it correctly. But this should not be the problem in itself
2. `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();` 
    This executeUpdate method should return a int based on the query itself. So it should return 1 **in your case** for the no of rows affected. So try to check what is returned.


   This may not be the exact solutions but do try these and you may get some idea on what is happening

Comment: it doesn't enter to the try scope in any case :(

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to use this one.

```
int status = 0; // to get the status to know if statement is executed properly or not

try {
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnect();//Your database Connection
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    status = st.executeUpdate(query); //After executing this it will return an int value
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it doesn't enter to the try scope in any case :(

Comment: two questions
1. is it printing any exception
2. or please post more code because it have to reach to try block to execute command, if it is not coming here it means there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: I use threading principle
public void run(){
double avarage_Bandwidth=0.1;
//the previous code 
}

Comment: @user3800610 sorry but i'm not able to understand your issue properly using your last comment

Comment: I mean:
the previous code was written in the post, existing into function called "run()"
this function works as thread and it reject "throw exception" in its header 
are you understanding? :$ 
I think the problem from the threading principle :(